# CollectionViewSource and sorting (Danish alphabet)

Tags: .net, sorting, cultureinfo, collectionviewsource

I would like to sort some objects that have a Name property. These objects are stored in CollectionViewSource. I add sorting description in the following way:

```
MyCollectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name"),direction));
```

where direction is Ascending/Descending. 
Everything works fine except one case. 
In Danish alphabet when I use for instance name: Aarhus or Aabenra it should be after "Z". So when I have the following names:
Silkeborg, Aarhus, Aabenraa, Odense it should be sorted as follows:

- Odense  Silkeborg  Aabenraa  Aarhus

however, currently it sorted as follows:

- Aabenraa Aarhus Odense Silkeborg

I tried to change culture info before each sorting but it doesn't work. 
SQL Server 2005 sort these values correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I set appropriate CultureInfo in MyCollectionViewSource.Culture property:

```
MyCollectionViewSource.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```